# Advance minibuffer-line to show things on the right site, even if mini-buffer is in use

Tags: minibuffer

I know there is [minibuffer-line](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/minibuffer-line.html) to display things in the minibuffer if it is not in use. I would like those things to be displayed from the right in the minibuffer, even if it is in use, how would i do that?
Could i possibly split the minibuffer?